# WPF bind CustomControl's property in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have following ListBox in my WPF application:

```
<ListBox x:Name="Domaci_soupiska" Margin="0" Background="#FFF1DE8A" AllowDrop="True" Drop="Soupiska_D_drop" Grid.Column="1">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="{Binding Typ, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <local:HracControl Hrac="{Binding Hrac, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Cas, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

which `ItemsSource` is `ObservableCollection<SoupiskaRow>` where the `SoupiskaRow` is a simple class:

```
public class SoupiskaRow
{
    public string Typ { get; set; }
    public Hrac Hrac { get; set; }
    public string Cas { get; set; }
}
```

and the `local:HracControl` is a `UserControl` with dependency property `Hrac` (pretty much just a storage). However when I add an item to the `ObervableCollecion` only "default" `HracControl` is created inside the ListBox - without any data set. Moreover, when I put breakpoint to the set part of `Hrac`dependency property the databinding does not even *try* to set this property.
The databinding sets the label context or textbox text just fine but I dont understand why it does not even attempt to set a custom property?
I found several threads on similar topic, but they suggested dropping any CustomControls and copy/paste its code into the `DataTemplate` of `ListBox`.
Code of HracControl is rather simple:

```
public Hrac Hrac
    {
        get { return (Hrac)GetValue(HracProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HracProperty, value);}
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HracProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Hrac", typeof(Hrac), typeof(HracControl) , new PropertyMetadata(new Hrac()));

    public HracControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public HracControl(Hrac hrac)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Hrac = hrac;
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
//and a methods for reordering/hiding some columns and drag/drop events
}
```

the inside of xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
...
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label x:Name="Hrac_ID" Content="{Binding Hrac.Hrac_ID}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label x:Name="Jmeno" Content="{Binding Hrac.Jmeno}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1"/>
...
</Grid>
```

*if you need more code, please let me know in comments*

Comment: You will not see wrapper property setter/getter get called for `DependencyProperty`. It calls directly `GetValue` and `SetValue`. As to your problem do you do something like `DataContex = this` in your `HracControl`?

Comment: Sure, I call `DataContex = this;` in the constructor. It might be the problem if it call it directly as part of my logic is in the `set{}`.

Comment: Each `FrameworkElement` can have **only one `DataContext`**. Either inherited through visual tree or set manually. When you set `DataContext` in control's constructor you change default binding context for control itself and all its children, including `<local:HracControl Hrac="{Binding ....}"/>`. Post you control code but instead of setting `DataContext` inside you need to change binding context per binding either via `ElementName` or `RelativeSource` binding. Long story short, at the moment you try to bind `HracControl.Hrac` to `HracControl.Hrac`

Comment: `DataTemplate` would be the simplier smarter choise here unless the custom control is absolutley necessary.  can you post the code for `local:HracControl`?

Comment: @dkozl can you please be more specific how to change it per binding?

Comment: @Omribitan I need drag/drop those controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment each `FrameworkElement` can have only one `DataContext`. It will be either inherited through visual tree or set manually.

```
public HracControl(Hrac hrac)
{
    ...
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

By doing this you change default binding context for control itself and all its children, including

```
<local:HracControl Hrac="{Binding Hrac....}"/>.
```

So it will search `Hrac` in `HracControl`, so it will try to bind `HracControl.Hrac` to `HracControl.Hrac`. Instead of setting `DataContext` manually in constructor you need to change binding context per binding either via `ElementName` or `RelativeSource` binding.

```
<UserControl ... x:Name="myControl">
    <Grid ...>
        <Label x:Name="Hrac_ID" Content="{Binding ElementName=myControl, Path=Hrac.Hrac_ID}" ... />
        <Label x:Name="Jmeno" Content="{Binding ElementName=myControl, Path=Hrac.Jmeno}" .../>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: The last part of your comment "Long story short, at the moment you try to bind HracControl.Hrac to HracControl.Hrac" was very helpful. It works now as intended, thanks.